# How to set up a singleton class as a delegate?

Tags: objective-c, ios, initialization

I have a class that is a singleton. This singleton is instantiated using GCD (via macro that uses a block), and is accessed by other objects via a class method. The problem is I need this singleton to be a delegate of other object.
Where(when) can I set this, I have no access to init, but I need to set this up soon, when the singleton instance is created.

Comment: I don't understand how this is different from setting any other delegate – just set the `delegate` property of your other object to be the singleton after you create it...

Comment: I do not create the singleton object..it is created by GrandCentralDispatch when it doesn't exist and when it is accessed by some other objects. More than one object has access to that singleton, and I do not know when. I mean, it is impossible to tell for sure that this or that will be the first one. Furthermore, I don't think its a good idea to set this singleton to be the delegate over and over, every time some object accesses it. Are you sure you understand the question at all?

Comment: As far as I understand your question, you want to set this singleton to be the delegate of _another object_, so it doesn't really matter when the singleton is created, it matters when _that other object_ is created and that's where you would typically set its delegate.

Comment: I tried it the way you describe and it of course works :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal behavior for a singleton is that, if it needs an internal instance, it creates one the **first** time it is referenced.  (I think that's what you're saying but it's not explicit.)  If that's the case, then it seems that the object that needs to have it as a delegate should simply assign it whenever **that object** is created.  So part of the init of the other object's creation would be:
`self.delegate = [MySingleton sharedInstance];`

I'm not sure it matters but is there a reason for making it a delegate instead of just using it whenever the object needs to, via something like:  `[[MySingleton sharedInstance] doSomething];`?

Comment: It's not possible. The delegator here is a built-in Cocoa touch framework class from Apple. I also have never seen such a practice, so far I have always seen the delegate setting itself to be the delegate. In other words, the initiative to be the delegate always came from the delegate.

Comment: If it's not possible in this case, that's fine but there are various other patterns in use, for example, an object making a 2nd object the delegate of a 3rd.  One reason that you seldom see an object set its own delegate is what I said in my second paragraph: if the object can find it on its own (like a singleton), the whole delegation idea loses its purpose.

Answer (score 1):

1. you create a class implements delegate
2. then in callback method

   ```
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:your-notification];
   ```
3. then in real

   ```
   implements viewController [center addObserver:self selector:@selector(your-delegate-mothed:) name:your-name object:nil];
   ```
4. finally:

   ```
   -(void)your-delegate-mothed:xx
    {
     //by NSNodificationCenter as gloal delegate ,dispatch callback
    }
   ```